# Focus bar is animating faster than keyboard in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uikeyboard

I am implementing a custom focus bar on top of my keyboard. The focus bar has widgets to move cursor back and forward along with a done button.

Now, with iOS 7, I am seeing the focus bar is moving faster than keyboard. Because of this for a second I see screen behind the focus bar before it sits on top of keyboard. This is working fine in iOS 6.

Below is what I am doing:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)iNotification {
    self.dismissForm = NO;
    self.shouldScrollCell = YES;
    CGFloat aKeyboardAnimationDuration = [[iNotification userInfo][UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect aKeyboardFrame = [[iNotification userInfo][UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect adjustedKeyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:aKeyboardFrame fromView:nil];
    CGFloat adjustedHeight;
    adjustedHeight = aKeyboardFrame.size.height + self.focusControlBar.frame.size.height;
    [self.focusControlBar viewForFocusControlWillShowWithEndFrame:adjustedKeyboardFrame andAnimationDuration:aKeyboardAnimationDuration];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^() {
        [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(kScreenOrigin, kScreenOrigin, adjustedHeight, 0.0f)];
        [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(kScreenOrigin, kScreenOrigin, adjustedHeight, 0.0f)];
    }];
}
```

This is my focus bar animation code:

```
- (void)viewForFocusControlWillShowWithEndFrame:(CGRect)iFrame andAnimationDuration:(CGFloat)iDuration {
    BOOL aShouldAppear = YES;   

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(focusControlBarShouldAppear:)]) {
        aShouldAppear = [self.delegate focusControlBarShouldAppear:self];
    }

    if (aShouldAppear) {
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(focusControlBarWillAppear:)]) {
            [self.delegate focusControlBarWillAppear:self];
        }
        CGRect aBarFrame = self.frame;
        UIInterfaceOrientation anInterfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
        aBarFrame.size.height = [self heightForOrientation:anInterfaceOrientation];
        self.frame = aBarFrame;
        aBarFrame.origin.y = self.superview.bounds.size.height - iFrame.size.height - aBarFrame.size.height;


        [UIView animateWithDuration:iDuration animations:^(void) {
            self.frame = aBarFrame;
        } completion:^(BOOL iFinished) {
            if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(focusControlBarDidAppear:)]) {
                [self.delegate focusControlBarDidAppear:self];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got to know that with iOS 7 we need to also keep KeyboardAnimationCurve into account. With the below modified code I had it worked.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)iNotification {
    self.dismissForm = NO;
    self.shouldScrollCell = YES;

    NSDictionary *aNotificationInfo = [iNotification userInfo];
    CGFloat aKeyboardAnimationDuration = [aNotificationInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve aKeyboardAnimationCurve = [aNotificationInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue];
    CGRect aKeyboardFrame = [aNotificationInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect adjustedKeyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:aKeyboardFrame fromView:nil];
    CGFloat adjustedHeight;
    adjustedHeight = aKeyboardFrame.size.height + self.focusControlBar.frame.size.height;

    [self.focusControlBar viewForFocusControlWillShowWithEndFrame:adjustedKeyboardFrame animationCurve:aKeyboardAnimationCurve andAnimationDuration:aKeyboardAnimationDuration];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^() {
        [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(kScreenOrigin, kScreenOrigin, adjustedHeight, 0.0f)];
        [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(kScreenOrigin, kScreenOrigin, adjustedHeight, 0.0f)];
    }];
}

- (void)viewForFocusControlWillShowWithEndFrame:(CGRect)iFrame animationCurve:(UIViewAnimationCurve)iAnimationCurve andAnimationDuration:(CGFloat)iDuration {
    BOOL aShouldAppear = YES;   

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(focusControlBarShouldAppear:)]) {
        aShouldAppear = [self.delegate focusControlBarShouldAppear:self];
    }

    if (aShouldAppear) {
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(focusControlBarWillAppear:)]) {
            [self.delegate focusControlBarWillAppear:self];
        }

        CGRect aBarFrame = self.frame;
        UIInterfaceOrientation anInterfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
        aBarFrame.size.height = [self heightForOrientation:anInterfaceOrientation];
        self.frame = aBarFrame;
        aBarFrame.origin.y = self.superview.bounds.size.height - iFrame.size.height - aBarFrame.size.height;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:iDuration delay:0.0 options:(iAnimationCurve << 16) animations:^{
            self.frame = aBarFrame;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(focusControlBarDidAppear:)]) {
                [self.delegate focusControlBarDidAppear:self];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be good if add UIViewAnimationOptionsBeginFromCurrentContext animation option in your animateWithDuration function.